# shell_exec is not working on my server

Tags: php, server, shell-exec

I am trying to run `shell_exec()` but it's returning a null value.

The following is the code I am trying to execute:

```
shell_exec("node /var/www/azon/application/third_party/scrap_amazon_usa_phrases.js watch")
```

but the above code return null on my server although it is working on another server.

So, anyone know the reason for it?

Is there need to activate `shell_exec()` on server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680504/php-shell-exec-doesnt-work-in-browser-but-works-in-terminal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986481/shell-exec-doesnt-run

What have you tested so far?

Comment: The command fails, can you run the command from cli? Check if nodejs is installed.